# Avoid OS pop-up while uploading file with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, file-upload

I am using selenium to upload a file. This is a problem because the upload button makes a file explorer window appear which I can't automate to my knowledge. How can I either automate file explorer or upload the file directly from selenium? It should select a specific file from a path to upload.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is my code:

```
upload1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(upload1xpath)
upload1.send_keys('C:\Users\bodig\Downloads\image1.jpg')
```

Comment: What is the problem here? You can't find the element to send the file xpath to it?

Comment: The problem is that the upload button opens a file explorer window for the user to select a file. I need it to select a file automatikly

Comment: Does your xpath `upload1xpath` have attribute `type = 'file' `?

Comment: Sure, that's why you should send the file path to some other element there to upload it, not to click on upload button. Can you share the link to that page?

Comment: Not really sorry as you have to sign in and its confidential. And by type = file do you mean a tag in the HTML?

Comment: yes do you see `input[type='file']` in entire web page ? Please use @ to reply.

Comment: @cruisepandey no it does not. it only has image-type="image"

Comment: @cruisepandey wait in the entire website i don't know il check

Comment: @cruisepandey I can't find any type = file tags. lots of other types but not file is this type usually in the button where you click to upload the file?

Comment: Press F12 (Dev tool) then go to Element section do CTRL + F and then write `input[type='file']` and see if there are any highlighted entry.

Comment: Is it really resolved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload a file without clicking the upload button in most cases you can send your file directly to some element on that page.
This will be element with `input` tag name with attribute type='file'. Not the button user clicking but somewhere near it.
So you can try finding that element with this:

```
upload_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="file"]')
upload.send_keys('C:\Users\bodig\Downloads\image1.jpg')
```

If you prefer using css_selector you can use this:

```
upload_input = driver.find_element_css_selector('input[type="file"]')
upload.send_keys('C:\Users\bodig\Downloads\image1.jpg')
```

To find specific element on your page I have to see the web page

Comment: This is a incomplete/incorrect answer. input tag with attribute `type='file'` is required to upload a file using `.send_keys()`

Comment: @cruisepandey you are right, thanks! I have corrected my answer

Comment: So I need to find this input element with [@type="file"] and use it as xpath correct?

Comment: Yes. You can use css_selector as well, I will add it too.

Comment: hmm, I can't find the type="file" is there a way I can find it?

Comment: It should be there!

Comment: in the button tab in the HTML?

Comment: No, I wrote you. It is some other element. With `input` tag name, not `button`, but it is often somewhere near the button element on the HTML

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.write('C:\\Users\\PlanetX\\Downloads\\erase\\python_imaging.jpg')
```

`pyautogui` is the equivalent of `Autohotkey` in Python. It sends keys on desktop/laptop blindly, so have to sure that the cursor is in the right place. It is a disadvantage but is a quick fix if you get stack with the OS pop up or where the //body, //tbody or driver.send_keys(). Don't work.